# How to use an object of a function inside a class from another script in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to run the below script for generating an email notification:

```
class ecom_common_functions_class(sendmailobject):
    def __init__(self):
        count = 0

    def ecom_send_mail_without_attachement(self,email_sender_id,email_reciever_id,mail_body,mail_subj,server):
        print "INSIDE MAIL SENT FUNCTION"
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        print "in function email_reciever_id =", email_reciever_id
        msg['From'] = email_sender_id
        msg['To'] = email_reciever_id
        msg['Subject'] = mail_subj
        body = mail_body
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(email_sender_id, email_reciever_id, text)
        server.quit()
```

When I import this function in another script I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ecom_data/US_full/binaries/NIS/aneesha/ecom_nis_validation_negative.py", line 10, in <module>
    import ecom_nis_common_functions
  File "/ecom_data/US_full/binaries/NIS/aneesha/ecom_nis_common_functions.py", line 32, in <module>
    class ecom_common_functions_class(sendmailobject):
NameError: name 'sendmailobject' is not defined
```

The result must be printed as a message in an email.

Comment: Well, where is the class `sendmailobject` defined, if at all?

Answer (score 1):

you have to import that class from the module, looks like you are not importing it or the code wasn't paste in its totality.

Answer (score 0):

`class ecom_common_functions_class(sendmailobject):` This line implies that your class `ecom_common_functions_class` wants to extends another class called `sendmailobject`. with `sendmailobject` name this does not seem to be class.

> Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.

Either you have not imported `sendmailobject` or it is not a `class`